# How i can read an Object within ionic 2 and angular 2?

Tags: arrays, json, angular, ionic-framework, ionic2

I've got an **object** from server and i want to **read** this within `ionic2` `typescript`.

my Question:

**How i can read this Object for each key getting their value ?**

**`Example:`**

`ionic` list with **header** :
in this case `Header = key1 , key2 , key3` and the `value` is the `values` of every `key`

```
Header = key1
items1
items1
items1
Header2 = key2
items2
items2
items2..
```

**The Object :**

```
{
    "status": "success",
    "products": {
        "Key1": [
            {
              "entity_id": "448",
              "sku": "587",
              "name": "name",
              "image_url": "587.png",
              "price": "15,000",
              "qty": 0,
              "rating": 0,
              "wishlist": false,
              "specialprice": "7,500",
              "brand": "brandname"
            }
        ],
        "Key2": [
            {
              "entity_id": "448",
              "sku": "587",
              "name": "name",
              "image_url": "587.png",
              "price": "15,000",
              "qty": 0,
              "rating": 0,
              "wishlist": false,
              "specialprice": "7,500",
              "brand": "brandname"
            }
        ],
        "Key3": [
            {
              "entity_id": "448",
              "sku": "587",
              "name": "name",
              "image_url": "587.png",
              "price": "15,000",
              "qty": 0,
              "rating": 0,
              "wishlist": false,
              "specialprice": "7,500",
              "brand": "brandname"
            }
        ],
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To print `"Key"` array in `*ngFor` loop, first write one `Pipes`

**Pipe.ts**

```
import { Component,Pipe, PipeTransform, Injectable } from '@angular/core';

@Pipe({
  name: 'objectValues'
})

@Injectable()
export class ObjectValuesPipe implements PipeTransform {
  transform(obj: any) {
    let result = [];
    for (var key in obj) {
      if (obj.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
        result.push(obj[key]);
      }
    }
    return result;
  }
}
```

do not forget to import your `Pipes` in `@NgModule`, than you can use this pipe like this.

```
<ul *ngFor="let item of items">
   <li *ngFor="let value of item | objectValues">
     {{ value }}
   </li>
 </ul>
```

Based On : [How to display json object using *ngFor and access key,value of object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40480467/how-to-display-json-object-using-ngfor-and-access-key-value-of-object)